# remove only <br /> from div content

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce and have had to include

```
    <br>
```

in a product name.

This break now shows up as

```
    <br />
```

in the .woocommerce-breadcrumb.

this is what the breadcrumb looks like:

```
    <nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
        <a href="http://localhost/WP">Home</a>
        &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://localhost/WP/product-category/guitars/">Guitars</a>
        &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://localhost/WP/product-category/guitars/electric-guitars/">Electric Guitars</a>
        &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;
        <a href="http://localhost/WP/product-category/guitars/electric-guitars/fender-electric-guitar/">Fender-123-electric-guitar</a>
        &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;Fender American Standard&lt;br /&gt; Stratocaster Sienna Sunburst
    </nav>
```

As you can see the last line before the nav contains the break which in the browser literally looks like < br  / >

At the moment I am trying this to get rid of it, but it breaks the breadcrumb's functionality!

```
  $(function() {
      $( '.woocommerce-breadcrumb' ).text(function(_,txt) {
          return txt.split('<br />').shift();
      });
  });
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` method is *destructive*, i.e. it resets  content of the element. You could iterate through the `childNodes` and modify `nodeValue` of the `textNode`s.

```
$( '.woocommerce-breadcrumb' ).contents().each(function() {
    if ( this.nodeType === 3 ) {
       this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/<br \/>/g, '');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zb8j43cu/

Comment: @MikeyMusch Just remember that <br> is self closing and does not have a closing slash in HTML. Remove that.

Comment: @Rob The `/` for _void_ elements is optional, http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: @Vohuman and ignored and pointless and useless. You will never find any spec showing a <br> element with a slash. NEVER. So don't do it. Pointless. Useless. Ignored.

Comment: @Rob Well, I didn't say it should be used or not. The point was it doesn't invalidate the document.

Comment: I didn't say it invalidated anything. I said it is pointless, useless and ignored.

Comment: @Rob in this case I am adding <br> to my woocommerce product title and when I inspect the output it's read as <br />